# How to insert a local image with custom size

Tags: php, images

I am not very familiar with PHP yet but I am trying to build a Wordpress theme.

In one of my theme files I simply want to insert an image (located at the theme directory /img/image.jpg) with a link to http://google.com

Since I have already included `add_image_size( 'testtest', 333, 333, true );` in my functions.php I would like to use this function to display the image at this size.

How should I write this with PHP code in my template file? In other words, how can I display an image that uses the pre-defined size and add a link to it with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[`add_image_size`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)** function has nothing to do with the images that are located in theme root directory.

When you add **[`add_image_size`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)** function , we are saying that :

Hey WordPress!  Can you please **also re-size** my uploaded images via **WordPress admin** to this particular size also hard crop the image if image size is bigger ( since third argument is set to `true` ).

So whenever we upload images after adding this function WordPress **generate** this extra size image in addition to default sizes. These generated images are available in `/wp-content/uploads/` folder by default unless you have changed the default uploads folder.

So to resize the image you need to upload the image via WP admin panel and look at the uploads folder.

> How should I write this with PHP code in my template file?

Generally this is used to get thumbnail attached to a post/page/CPT, like

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'testtest' );
```

The above function generates required html for image tag.

Comment: Oh I see... I got the whole thing wrong here. I thought the `add_image_size` could be applied to any image in the template.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you wan use image from theme dir, then you should create all sizes image
   e.g. logo_300x300, logo_fullsize, logo_small,...
2. You can upload image with `media_handle_sideload` function, more information https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_sideload